# Verbal Job Offer - Delays on Written Offer

Tags: job-offer, technology

I've been talking with a company since late August for a role.  After several rounds of interviews I accepted a verbal offer.  Last Wednesday I was anticipating one by Friday, which I called the recruiter up and he told me that they are waiting on a CFO sign off who is out of the country and I should hear back something Monday.

I didn't receive anything Monday so I contacted the recruiter today and got a quick response back apologizing to me for the delay.  He emailed this

"We are working through a couple obstacles internally to acquire the financial and managerial approval we need. I’m hoping this will complete very soon."

I'm not sure if they are giving me the runaround or if they are being as transparent as possible. Many roles are being posted as they are hiring.  I also saw my role amongst others reposted on LI.  Not sure if all of this should raise concern or if these roadblocks are standard in certain organizations.

Should this raise suspicion on my end that I may not get a formal offer, another candidate is in the background, or these delays are quite standard?  Thank you.

Comment: Most organizations have to get several clearances before purchasing or even hiring new recruits. It is not rare to find these "obstacles". Now, if they are doing that on purpose (as a way for you to lose interest in the job) or if they are indeed having some obstacles we can't possibly know, we would be speculating if we answered that.

Comment: That being said @BrandonAntone , I feel your post lacks a goal that we can address. Asking if we have any "Thoughts" can only end up with ambiguous and opinionated answers. Can you please edit your post to be more answerable, with an actual goal you want to achieve? If you may, I suggest you read [how to ask](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to get ideas on how to improve this post. Welcome to The Workplace :) feel free to comment if you have further doubts.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my initial post.  I was just wondering if this should raise any high concern on my end.

Answer (score 2):

> Should this raise suspicion on my end that I may not get a formal offer, another candidate is in the background, or these delays are quite standard?

All three are possible, but most likely is because **these delays are not rare** to come across. Several companies (mostly the bigger ones) have to get several clearances before purchasing or even hiring new recruits. It is not rare to find these "obstacles".

That being said, you should always keep your options open, and don't rely just on this job offer. I suggest you search of other options, in case that this offer ends up being rejected.

If I were you, I would not over think this too much. It's only been *one* day since they replied, so maybe give it a bit more time before you make any conclusions.

Comment: I agree, at my current position I was practically given a verbal offer at the end of the interview, however it took about 3 weeks until I received a formal offer letter.  I can also confirm the clearances, I need three separate signatures( not including my own ) for a purchase order of _any_ amount.

Answer (score 1):

> Should this raise suspicion on my end that I may not get a formal
>   offer, another candidate is in the background, or these delays are
>   quite standard?

Delays happen. While there's no reason to doubt their explanation at this point, there's no way to know the real reason.

The fact that the role is reposted on LinkedIn may or may not mean anything. Often HR will do this automatically until a formal (usually written) offer and acceptance has been completed.

I've been on the hiring manager end of things many, many times. In some companies, approval is required from Finance and sometimes up several layers of management. From a manager's point of view this is a major pain in the neck, as I'm sure it is from the candidate's point of view. But sometimes there's no way to shortcut the process.

Since there's nothing you can really do about it anyway, your best bet is to try and be patient. You'll know the outcome soon.

That said, I hope you have continued your job search. As they say, it's not over 'til it's over.